# String input in java using Scanner class and after already taken a integer input from user

Tags: java

I am concatenating two Strings but the problem is that the String input taken from the user is after i have taken a integer and double input from the user.
Taking input from user is only using Scanner class in java. This is because i am regularly failing in test cases. And i have checked many sites they all said it is not possible. And i have to take a string input of 6-7 words minimum.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z49lk.png)

Comment: Posting images of code and errors is frowned upon here, because it makes it more difficult for us to help you with your issue.  It is always better to copy and paste the relevant code and/or errors into your question directly.  Please read [Why not to upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-to-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question), then [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: Also, it's not clear exactly what you are asking here.  Can you include a question with your edit?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is `scan.nextLine();` instead of `scan.next()`; because `scan.next();` is taking input before space only. If you want to take input with spaces, you should use `scan.nextLine();`. Refer documentation.